# Subsetting odd rows in r using seq

Tags: r, seq

Hope it is not a too newbie question.

I am trying to subset rows from the GDP UK dataset that can be downloaded from here:
http://www.ons.gov.uk/ons/site-information/using-the-website/time-series/index.html

The dataframe looks more or less like that:

```
       X    ABMI
1   1948    283297
2   1949    293855
3   1950    304395
```

....

```
300 2013 Q2 381318
301 2013 Q3 384533
302 2013 Q4 387138
303 2014 Q1 390235
```

The thing is that for my analysis I only need the data for years 2004-2013 and I am interested in one result per year, so I wanted to get every fourth row from the dataset that lies between the 263 and 303 row.

On the basis of the following websites:

https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-June/165634.html
(plus a few that i cannot quote due to the link limit)

I tried the following, each time getting some error message:

```
> GDPUKodd <- seq(GDPUKsubset[263:302,], by = 4)
    Error in seq.default(GDPUKsubset[263:302, ], by = 4) : 
  argument 'from' musi mieæ d³ugoœæ 1

> OddGDPUK <- GDPUK[seq(263, 302, by = 4)]
    Error in `[.data.frame`(GDPUK, seq(263, 302, by = 4)) : 
  undefined columns selected

> OddGDPUKprim <- GDPUK[seq(263:302), by = 4]
Error in `[.data.frame`(GDPUK, seq(263:302), by = 4) : 
  unused argument (by = 4)

> OddGDPUK <- GDPUK[seq(from=263, to=302, by = 4)]
Error in `[.data.frame`(GDPUK, seq(from = 263, to = 302, by = 4)) : 
  undefined columns selected

> OddGDPUK <- GDPUK[seq(from=GDPUK[263,] to=GDPUK[302,] by = 4)]
Error: unexpected symbol in "OddGDPUK <- GDPUK[seq(from=GDPUK[263,] to"

> GDPUK[seq(1,nrows(GDPUK),by=4),]
Error in seq.default(1, nrows(GDPUK), by = 4) : 
  could not find function "nrows"
```

To put a long story short: help!

Comment: Try `GDPUK[seq(263, 302, by=4),]` it seems you only missed a comma telling r that you want all columns.

Comment: Welcome. But @janos is right about cleaning the data first which will make your subset more robust than if you only rely on row order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to extract data based on row ids, you can use the `subset` function with appropriate filters based on the values.

For example if your data frame has a `year` column with values 1948...2014 and a `quarter` column with values Q1..Q4, then you can get the right subset with:

```
subset(data, year >= 2004 & year <= 2013 & quarter == 'Q1')
```

**UDATE**

I see your source data is *dirty*, with no proper year and quarter columns. You can clean it like this:

```
x <- read.csv('http://www.ons.gov.uk/ons/datasets-and-tables/downloads/csv.csv?dataset=pgdp&cdid=ABMI')
x$ABMI <- as.numeric(as.character(x$ABMI))
x$year <- as.numeric(gsub('[^0-9].*', '', x$X))
x$quarter <- gsub('[0-9]{4} (Q[1-4])', '\\1', x$X)
subset(x, year >= 2004 & year <= 2013 & quarter == 'Q1')
```

Comment: I am afraid Q1..Q4 are not separate columns, as previously the data was collected on only a yearly basis. It is part of the year column now.

Comment: Thank you for it. It was of special interest to me to see how to use the data directly from the website they are at. There will be more challenges for me though, as using any of the two methods the ABMI variable is treated as a factor variable and I cannot regress against it :>

Comment: Maybe `as.numeric(x$ABMI)` can help with that?

Comment: somehow it is not that easy. it is not the first time it is happening to me, and up till now I would end up creating a separate vector c(..) "per hand"...

Comment: I see your point, how about: `as.numeric(as.character(x$ABMI))`

Comment: > c
 [1] 339967 368801 358067 380077 424596 461421 495884 498119 455414 471451
> GDPUKodd$ABMI    As I only need 10 numbers it will be quicker to do  it per hand again ;) Thank you anyway
 [1] 351975 358872 373227 382040 392786 366124 368033 374264 376437 378439
308 Levels:  101333 101497 102337 102840 103463 105084 105152 105217 ... seasonal_adjustment='SA'

Comment: Nooooo! It's good to get used to not doing things by hand ;-) I added a step in my answer to fix that column.

Answer (score 0):

Your code `GDPUK[seq(1,nrows(GDPUK),by=4),]` actually works quite well for these purposes. The only thing you need to change is `nrow` for `nrows`.